# How to set default month and year in mat-calendar using Angular( Material )?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I have a requirement to set default Month and Year in multiple mat calendars using Angular.

Created Result :

[image]

Expected Result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [Material Documenation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-calendar-starting-view) suggets you can provide value to a startDate and startView.
In your situation you might use following:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker start date */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-start-view-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-start-view-example.html'
})
export class DatepickerStartViewExample {
  startDate = new Date(2021, 0, 1);
}
```

Initializing `startDate` in your component

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker startView="month" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And adding `startAt` property to your HTML, and giving `startView` property value of month to open up `DatePicker` with a month selection.